# recv() doesn't wait for incoming messages

Tags: c++, sockets, server

I'm trying to write my own webserver and i have got some problem with recv() function. I debugged my program and found out that everytime when i am reaching this line

```
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address, sizeof(server_address)) < 0) {
    cout << "[Client] Connection failed" << endl;
}
```

I'm getting in server side program and program continues there. And, despite of  that i haven't sent the message from client side, recv() function get something (but it should not work like this, right? recv() should be blocked until client's message come). I checked this message, and this one is absolutely empty.

My tcp server implementation:

```
void tcp_server::connection_handler(int socket) {
    char read_buffer[128000];
    memset(&read_buffer, 0, sizeof(read_buffer));

    while ((static_cast<size_t>(recv(socket, read_buffer, 128000, 0))) > 0) {
        cout << "[Server] Client message accepted" << endl;
        cout << "[Server] Client message: " << endl << read_buffer << endl;

        string converted_message_for_send = convert_client_message(read_buffer);

        if (send(socket, converted_message_for_send.c_str(), converted_message_for_send.size(), 0) == -1) {
            cout << "[Server] Message send failure" << endl;
        }

        cout << converted_message_for_send << endl;

        cout << "[Server] Message sent to client" << endl << endl;
        cout << "============================" << endl << endl;

        memset(&read_buffer, 0, 128000);
    }
}

void tcp_server::take_requests() {
    int client_socket;
    while (true) {
        client_socket = accept(listener_socket, (struct sockaddr*)& server_address, &socket_length);
        cout << "----------------------------" << endl << endl;
        cout << "[Server] New connection accepted" << endl << endl;
        cout << "----------------------------" << endl << endl;

        thread handling_thread(&tcp_server::connection_handler, this, client_socket);
        handling_thread.detach();
    }
}
```

My driver program:

```
TEST_CASE("Check base read/send functions","Client") {
unsigned short int PORT = 8080;
int sockfd;
struct sockaddr_in server_address{};

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

memset(&server_address, '0', sizeof(server_address));
server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_address.sin_port = htons(PORT);
if (inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &server_address.sin_addr) == 0) {
    cout << "[Server] Invalid IP address" << endl;
}

if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address, sizeof(server_address)) < 0) { // im getting in server side program here while debugging
    cout << "[Client] Connection failed" << endl;
}
cout << "[Client] All setting are done" << endl;
cout << "[Client] Succefully connected to the server" << endl << endl;
cout << "----------------------------" << endl << endl;

string message = "GET /tutorials/other/top-20-mysql-best-practices/ HTTP/1.1\n"
        "Host: net.tutsplus.com\n"
        "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)\n"
        "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8*\n"
        "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\n"
        "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\n"
        "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\n"
        "Keep-Alive: 300\n"
        "Connection: keep-alive\n"
        "Cookie: PHPSESSID=r2t5uvjq435r4q7ib3vtdjq120\n"
        "Pragma: no-cache\n"
        "Cache-Control: no-cache\n"
        "\n";
if (write(sockfd, message.c_str(), message.size()) == -1) {
    cout << "[Client] Message sending failed" << endl;
}
cout << "[Client] Message sent to server" << endl;

char buffer[128000];

memset(&buffer, 0, 128000);
read(sockfd, buffer, 128000);

string received_message = string(buffer);

string proper_response = "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n"
        "Content-Length: 26\n"
        "\n"
        "Oops! Something went wrong\n";

REQUIRE(received_message == proper_response);

cout << "[Client] Server message: " << buffer << endl;
cout << "============================" << endl << endl;
```

}

So, the first problem is: i need to force recv() wait for messages from client. And the second problem is: when i'm getting in server side program (on the socket connecting step), i need to return back to client side program (to send message from client).

Comment: I think the end of line for `HTTP` is supposed to be `"\r\n"`.

Comment: You are not checking result of `recv` properly and therefore don't know how many bytes were actually received. Printing potentially not null-terminated buffer `read_buffer` is not a good idea either, it may print garbage characters, read out of bounds or not printed some of the received characters after '\0'.

Comment: If you check for errors after the call it may tell you why it returned immediately. Something like `if((len = read(sockfd, buffer, 128000)) == -1) std::cerr << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';`

Comment: "recv() should be blocked until client's message come" - or timeout exceeded; or return immediately if set to non-blocking.

Comment: @Galik thanks! actually it is very useful thing, i added this one to my program and found out that error is: "Bad file descriptor"

Comment: but i still cant realize why recv() function tries to get message without sending of message  from client

Comment: 1) A message can be longer than 128000 bytes leaving you with only part of it. 2) recv can (and will) return early if interrupted by a signal. 3) a request can be shorter than 1280000 bytes and followed by another. you get 2 or more requests in one buffer. (pipelining) 1+2+3) you need to write a parser that you feed chunks of data and that tells you every time a full request was received. Can be one every few chunks or many in one chunk. Handle that properly. 4) the socket may be set to non-blocking so recv returns if nothing is available to read. As other said: output the error

Comment: You might also be trying to recv from the bound socket because the connect signals the socket is ready for read. But what you should do is accept(). Hard to say without complete source.

Comment: okay, looks like the problem was in the socket accepting, when it happpens my socket sets to -1
this line doesn't work properly:
`client_socket = accept(listener_socket, (struct sockaddr*)& server_address, &socket_length);`